# TemplateDoesNotExist - Django 1.8 normal loaders with nested prj/apps/app1 dir

Tags: python, django

I'm setting up a new django 1.8 project, but my app templates are not loaded from the `app/template` dir. A regular view snippet:

```
return render_to_response('pcmanage/index.html', {
    'msg': msg,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Possibly a spicy detail. My apps are in:

```
project
    apps/app1
    apps/app2
```

Path that works (taken from within `project`):

`templates/pcmanage/index.html`

Paths that don't work:

`apps/pcmanage/templates/pcmanage/index.html`

`pcmanage/templates/pcmanage/index.html`

My settings files are in a settings dir in the project basedir. initiated via:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.settings_debug
```

Significant settings info:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'pcmanage',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I also tried adding `apps.pcmanage` to `INSTALLED_APPS` but no luck.

Template-loader postmortem:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/path2env/project/templates/wpcmanage/pillar_view.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/path2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/wpcmanage/pillar_view.html (File does not exist)
/path2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrap3/templates/wpcmanage/pillar_view.html (File does not exist)
/path2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_admin_bootstrapped/templates/wpcmanage/pillar_view.html (File does not exist)
/path2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/wpcmanage/pillar_view.html (File does not exist)
/path2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admindocs/templates/wpcmanage/pillar_view.html (File does not exist)
/path2env/project/apps/wpcmanage/templates/wpcmanage/pillar_view.html (File exists)
/path2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/templates/wpcmanage/pillar_view.html (File does not exist)
```

I would gladly post any other info that is needed.

Comment: `/path2env/project/apps/wpcmanage/templates/wpcmanage/pillar_view.html (File exists) ` Django found your template, isn't it?

Comment: Django is looking for a `wpcmanage` directory, but you have mentioned naming things `pcmanage`. I'm curious if you've misnamed something somewhere...

Comment: @number5 .. Django did find it , i overlooked it .. but it still gives me TemplateDoesNotExist!?

Comment: @mevius, the name issue is only in the displayed output (writing docs as well :)

Comment: found the issue guys ... thanx!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the template file itself.

It extended a non existing template from an old app

```
{% extends 'otherapp/pillar__base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Salty Front</h1>

    {{ msg }}

{% endblock %}
```